Authentication Error with Angular App Deployed to Azure App Service
I'm encountering an authentication error when deploying my Angular application, which is located in the wwwroot folder of my .NET project,
to an Azure App Service.
Details: .Net 8.0
Issue:
After deploying, when I try to access the application, I receive an authentication error.
Error Message:
The specific error message I'm receiving is:
Authentication failed. Please try again.
Questions:

Are there any specific configurations required for serving Angular apps from the wwwroot folder in Azure?
Could this be related to how authentication tokens are handled between the Angular app and the .NET backend?
Any insights on how to debug authentication issues in this context?

The application runs fine locally without any authentication issues.

How you are deploying your app?

Using VS2022 publish option and selecting the appropriate Azure Subscription and Service

@ChiruCharan Please share your Project structure.

@ChiruCharan Are you using Azure Ad?

@AsleshaKantamsetti. Deployed application is using on premise Active directory authentication. Same application is deployed to App Service. Do we need to make any changes to the app when deployed to Azure to use the same.. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

@ChiruCharan Are you using the Visual Studio .NET + Angular template?

@ChiruCharan Is your backend and frontend deployed separately on Azure?
